# Can I provided 3.3V regulated directly to the BBB

Tags: power-supply, beaglebone-black

I have a project where I need to be mobile and I draw a lot of power (4 BBB, 5 Port switch, 26 cameras). All of the cameras and the control circuits run at 3.3V - I'd love it if I could just deliver 3.3V at the main power connector and ignore the BBB 5V jack - is it possible to provide 3.3V to the BBB ? I swear I'll keep it well regulated (or pay the butchers bill if I don't)

Comment: Well, does the device offer support for providing non-5V power? I would expect not because you need to run the USB. Also, you probably want multiple point-of-load regulators with a higher distribution voltage to avoid having a lot of current across long wires at 3.3V.

Comment: Building on @user2943160 point, which I think is important and useful advice, providing mobile power to 35 devices is not trivial. So, how mobile, and how long do you need to be mobile? You might want something traditional and robust like Sealed Lead Acid, at 12 volts. In which case a bunch of DC-DC converters might be an efficient way to solve your problems.

Comment: What is a BBB?. Never mind, just read the tag.

Comment: Hey, @user2943160 - paste that in as an answer and I'll accept it - I hadn't thought the whole thing through -

Comment: @MarkMullin done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the device offer support for providing non-5V power? I would expect not because the BeagleBone Black is a USB host.

While this is an answer of Y for an X, it was requested as such:

You probably want multiple point-of-load regulators with a higher distribution voltage to avoid having a lot of current across long wires at 3.3V. This would allow the use of thinner wires to distribute a higher voltage to each cluster of devices, then use regulators (switching buck regulators recommended) to supply 3.3V or 5V as required. Typical nominal voltages could be 12V and 24V, depending on the regulators chosen, power demands, and power supply availability.

Using a higher supply voltage would also decouple the mobile battery voltage from the supply voltage of the numerous devices.

Additional advice: try to keep power and signal grounds separated to avoid too much current flow in the shields of your signal cables between cameras and switches.